# How to read a specific key by value from properties file in java

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, internationalization

Iam working with spring internationalization I have 3 messages properties file iam using MessageSource to read values by key like following example.

```
        String value = messageSource.getMessage("key", null,LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
```

but I want to read key by a specific value is there any solution.

Comment: There is no way to read a key by a value from a MessageSource. You also cannot iterate over all keys. So you have to read the properties file in a java.util.Properties and the iterate over all entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose properties by creating :

```
public class ExposedResourceBundleMessageSource extends
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {
    public Properties getMessages(Locale locale) {
        return getMergedProperties(locale).getProperties();
    }
}
```

Then declare it in your configuration :

```
@Bean
public ExposedResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ExposedResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ExposedResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    source.setCacheSeconds(0);
    source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return source;
}
```

Autowire it with :

```
@Autowired
private ExposedResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;
```

Then you can search by value :

```
String searchTerm = "foo";
Entry<Object, Object> entry = messageSource.getMessages(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()).entrySet().stream().filter(
        e -> ((String) e.getValue()).equals(searchTerm)).findFirst().orElse(null);
String key = (String) entry.getKey();
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question: Merwis want to find a key by value.